# facing problem in importing python package pytube in sudo su mode

Tags: python, pytube

when I imported pytube in normal mode it works just fine,
but when i do the same on superuser it gives error saying 
`ImportError: No module named pytube`

[image: left is without super user and right is with super user.]

wanted to use it in file management so needed superuser in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice the Python interpreter is different. On su mode you are accessing the python 2.7 and on normal user you are accessing the python 3.6 of Anaconda. Module path is different for each interpreter. You can be explicit by saying python3 or python2. Or check your Environment variables.